# What SQL query needed to solve this question?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

What SQL query needed to solve this question "You have a table with the columns 'reservation_id', 'check-in date', and 'check out date'. Write an SQL query that gives you the average length of stay."

Comment: One that starts with `SELECT`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

With Postgres you can use the following:

```
select avg(check_out_date - check_in_date)
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use script like below. If I understood clearly.

> Select  AVG(datediff(day,checkin,checkout)) from xxx